# Linux Install Needed Packages for Executable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, executable, package

I'm trying to run the executable FiniteField as you can see below, but it seems I need some missing packages, so I try to see what I'm missing using the objdump command.

It seems the command will list packages needed whether or not I already have them, and this can begin to be tedious as you can see for example it says I need libQtGui.so.4.  I try to install it using several names and then, getting it right, realize I already have it.

So the names of what I need don't exactly match what I would enter in a "sudo apt-get install ___" phrase.

How can I go about installing everything I need just so I can run my executable successfully?

**./FiniteField**

```
bash: ./FiniteField: No such file or directory
```

**objdump -x FiniteField | grep NEEDED**

```
  NEEDED               libQtGui.so.4
  NEEDED               libQtCore.so.4
  NEEDED               libpthread.so.0
  NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
  NEEDED               libm.so.6
  NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
```

**sudo apt-get install libQtGui.so.4**

```
E: Unable to locate package libQtGui.so.4
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libQtGui.so.4'
```

**sudo apt-get install libqtgui**

```
E: Unable to locate package libqtgui
```

**sudo apt-get install libqtgui4**

```
libqtgui4 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 476 not upgraded.
```

Comment: where did this "executable" come from?

Comment: Unzipped/untarred it from a compressed file received from a professor

Comment: Silly question here -- is this a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit platform? If so, you may need to install 32-bit compatibility packages.

Comment: I'd also look for some instructions with a list of package dependencies (or maybe ask the professor?)

Comment: BTW, this isn't really a programming question as such; http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/ would be a better forum.

Comment: ...btw, in the future, I'd suggest reaching for `ldd` before `objdump` for this kind of issue.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu; if you're lucky, `apt-get install ia32-libs` may get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

objdump displays library names.

apt-get expects package names, not library names (libraries are inside packages).

You can use rpmfind.net to find the names of the packages that contain the libraries you need, like this:

http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libQtGui.so.4

In this case you're looking for the package **qt-x11** (eventually with a version number fitted for your system if apt-get can't figure out a version by itself with just the name).

Comment: That's true, but `libc.so.6` means we have more basic unmet dependencies -- bigger than just needing to install a few libraries, we either need a new architecture (ie. 32-bit vs existing 64-bit), or a different libc version (in which case we're pretty much sunk, unless we want to do something painful like install a chroot of a different OS/distro version).

Comment: (Also, http://rpmfind.net/ isn't a very helpful suggestion for someone explicitly on Ubuntu; package names aren't always identical between distros; see instead http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: That means the executable is not really built/usable for your system. Either get a new executable or a new system (chroot is an option) :)

Comment: I think I said that in my first comment, didn't I? :)

Comment: Note: libc.so.6 is typically just a symlink to whatever version of the library the system has, it's just a _compatibility_ version. You don't need to find the exact one, just one good-enough.

Comment: true, rpmfind.net is not perfect, but it's a start. I didn't say find the exact rpm to use, I said find the package name(s) and let apt-get try to figure out the rest. Yes, it's possible the packaging is different on your system, but it's also possible it's not different and the recipe can actually work and get you going. You just have to try (especially if you don't have a better idea).

Comment: BTW - rpmfind.net also displays packages for apt-get based systems :) Sure, a ubuntu-specific DB would be better in your case, assuming you find the info you need.